# Which files to publish? ASP .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on hosting my first ever Asp.net core 2.0 website.
To bundle the project I ran "`dotnet publish`"
This created the following folder structure for publish:

```
/wwwroot
/appsettings.Development.json
/appsettings.json
/ProjectName.deps.json
/ProjectName.dll
/ProjectName.pdb
/ProjectName.PreCompiledViews.dll
/ProjectName.PreCompiledViews.pdb
/ProjectName.runtimeconfig.json
/package.json
/package-lock.json
/web.config
```

Q1. Which files do I need to copy over to my FTP server? Are all files necessary?

Q2. Where could I find some description as to what each file is?

Comment: All of them? The whole point of publishing is to compile your application down to what's necessary for it to be run somewhere else. Therefore, the result of publishing is what you copy. Now granted, some things are only necessary in certain contexts (Web.config is useless unless you're hosting in IIS), but it's not going to hurt to have those there even if they end up not being strictly necessary.

Comment: everything in publish! duh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **wwwroot** - static files
- **appsettings.Development.json** - environment-specific settings
- **appsettings.json** - general settings
- **ProjectName.deps.json** - NuGet package manifest
- **ProjectName.dll** - compiled project code
- **ProjectName.pdb** - symbols for compiled project code (debugging)
- **ProjectName.PreCompiledViews.dll** - compiled views
- **ProjectName.PreCompiledViews.pdb** - symbols for compiled views (debugging)
- **ProjectName.runtimeconfig.json** - runtime configuration (namely what version of .NET Core runtime to target)
- **package.json** - node.js package references
- **package-lock.json** - [node.js lock file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json)
- **web.config** - IIS hosting configuration

About the only things you could get rid of are the *.pdb files (but you wouldn't be able to debug the application), the package*.json files (but you won't be able to restore node.js packages) and web.config (but only if not hosting in IIS).

Comment: What about the `runtimes` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think (didn't work on it yet) :
**wwwroot** + **dlls** generated after the build.

**wwwroot** contains the static contents (css, js, images ..).

You can [read this](https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/) internet should be full of articles helps you with this topic.